# User defined functions in c are not switching

Tags: c

**problem**
I was making a c program in which users details are accepted checked and added to a file
but while compile the functions are not changing i meant it only asks the name and the program end
can someone please help me out!

````
#include <string.h>
void main()
void regis_name();
void regis_dob();
void regis_pin();
void check();

//checks code is not added here 

{
     int a, i, j, n, b, f = 1, d[1], m[1], y[1], f1 = 1;
    int *a1, *d1[1], *m1[1], *y1[1];
    a1 = a;
    d1[1] = &d[1];
    m1[1] = &m[1];
    y1[1] = &y[1];
    regis_pin();

void regis_name()
{
    char name[3];
    printf("ADD YOUR NAME: \n ");
    scanf("%s", name[3]);
   regis_dob(); // to dob
}
bd
void regis_dob()
{
    int a, i, j, n, b, f = 1, d[1], m[1], y[1], f1 = 1;
    printf("enter date in 'dd' month in 'mm' year in 'yyyy' \n \n");
    printf("enter dd:   \n");
    scanf("%d", &d[1]);
    printf("enter mm:   \n");
    scanf("%d", &m[1]);
    printf("enter yyyy:  \n");
    scanf("%d", &y[1]);
   regis_pin; // to pin
}
void regis_pin()
{
    int a;
    printf("ADD A PASS CODE OF 4 DIGIT:  \n");
    scanf("%d", &a);
    printf("\n");
    check(); // to pin check
}```
````

Comment: The code presented is not valid C.  Some parts of it do form complete C function definitions, but none of those store the data they read anywhere that would be visible outside the function itself.

Comment: @JohnBollinger arent the scanf enough to read functions i have added pointers to the program to pass values

Comment: @JohnBollinger may i get what should i change to get it working

Comment: Yes, `scanf` reads data.  It is a question of where you have asked it to store the results, which in every case shown is a *local variable* of the function containing the `scanf` call.  That's fine as far as `scanf` is concerned, but those local variables are only visible within the function.  You need either to store the data somewhere with longer persistence and wider visibility, or to convey it to other functions and / or back to the caller by using the various functions' argument lists and return values.

Comment: Don't use integers to hold a PIN, unless you want `00042` to be the same PIN as `42`.  There is typically no need to have arrays of length `1`. In addition, array indexes start at zero, so in your case you are accessing the arrays out of bounds.

Comment: As @JohnBollinger said, the code you have shown us won't compile. If you have problem compiling, you should post the error message. If you have codes that compiles, you should post that code. We can't help you if the code you have posted is not the same the code you have.

Comment: @Abhiram `char name[3];` is too small for the name. `scanf("%d", &d[1]);` is out of range for a `d[1]` and the wrong type.  `regis_pin;` does nothing.  Save time, enable all warnings.